# Find files that are missing between two folders

Tags: linux, find, md5sum

I'm looking for a way to find the files within a folder and its sub-folders that are not duplicated (i.e. missing) in another folder and sub-folders. But search should be performed in only one direction: search files from folder1 in folder2 but not the files from folder2 in folder1.

Trying to clarify...

I'm having a folder in which I'm uploading all the photos of my iphone using bittorentSync.
This folder is having sub-folders according the iphone galery (e.g. 100APPLE, 101APPLE, 102APPLE...).

I'm having another folder which hosts my library of photos. Inside this folder, Photos are stored in sub-folders named with year, then sub folder named with year-month. Photos are renamed using 'year_month_day-XXX.jpg' where xxx is the photo number.

The structure looks like:

```
2010/2010-06/2010_06_02-001.jpg
2010/2010-06/2010_06_02-002.jpg
2012/2012-08/2012_08_09-001.jpg
2012/2012-08/2012_08_09-002.jpg
2012/2012-08/2012_08_09-003.jpg
```

I'm using the following command to search the files that are not existing in other folders. As files are being renamed, I need to use md5sum to compare the files.

```
 find iphoneSync PhotosLib -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | sort | uniq --unique -w 30 > ListFilesToCopy.txt
```

This works fine, but it is searching in both directions... i.e. search files from iphoneSync into PhotosLib, but also files from PhotosLib into iphoneSync.

I would like to prevent the second direction search, i.e. files from PhotosLib into iphoneSync. iphoneSync contains around 300 photos whereas PhotosLib (and sub-folders) contains more than 10'000 files...

For the moment as search gives results of both direction search I'm obliged to use this command to copy the files missing from PhotosLib in my temp folder:

```
cp $( awk -F"iphoneSync" 'NF>1{ print "iphoneSync"$2 }' ListFilesToCopy.txt ) AmokTempDir/
```

The reason of using temp dir is because I used Amok Exif Sorter to automatically move and rename, according the Exif data, my photos in the correct sub-folders of PhotosLib.

I look forward any advice or tips to make this search in only one direction to be more efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By comparing via hashes, there's a limit to how efficient you can be. You have to perform the hash of every file in both sets, which is an exceedingly expensive operation for large files. And then you still have to sort at least one list and search it (sorting both maybe faster depending on their sizes).

You could speed this up considerably by maintaining sorted md5sum's of all files in PhotosLib offline, and only needing to search it with each potentially new file.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really good advice. I'll look at implementing such optimization